# The verb "propose" with the indirect object

Tags: transitivity, indirect-objects

Is this sentence gramatically correct? Is it acceptable to use the indirect object (*us*) here?

> They proposed us a plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It definitely does not sound correct. The verb "propose" is almost always followed by the preposition "to" when connecting to an 'object' receiving the proposal. The object could be a person, a group of people (like a committee), etc. So, one correct way to write it would be

> They proposed to us a plan.

Further, in this case, you should move the "a plan" part to just after the verb as well. So *I would propose to you the following as the best usage* in this scenario:

> They proposed a plan to us.

The case where you do skip the "to" after propose while connecting it to people or a group of people would be when the person or the group itself is being proposed. For instance,

> They proposed Robert for the post of CEO.

[This link](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/propose) has some more examples of usage of the verb propose.

Answer (score 2):

With **propose** it is normal to identify the recipient with a prepositional phrase:

> They proposed a plan **to us**.
>
> We proposed it **to them**.

Unlike **offer**:

> They offered **us** a meal.
>
> We offered **them** a full refund.